# Using lapply with variable argument lists

Tags: r, subset, lapply

Oh man I feel dumb. This is beginner central, but I'm totally lost trying to figure out how to subset arguments in `lapply`. At this point I've just been randomly trying different combinations of `[[` and friends, cursing my clumsiness with the debugging in RStudio.

**The issue:** I have a dataset collected from SQL Server which includes several columns of date data. Some of these are legitimate `datetime` values, others are strings. Most have (valid) missing data and some have more than one format. Often the date `1900-01-01` is used as a substitute for `NULL`. I'm trying very, very hard to be idiomatic and concise in solving this instead of brute forcing it with copy/paste invocations.

My `ParseDates()` function seems to work well if called column-by-column, but I can't get it to work with `lapply`. I can see that I'm sending the whole list of `orders` and `threshold` values when I only want to pass the current observation, but I can't get my head around how `lapply` iterates or how to align multiple lists so that the right arguments go with the right call.

I need to finish with all values correctly held as dates (or `POSIXct` in this instance) with anything close to `1900-01-01` set to `NA`.

```
library(lubridate)

# build sample data extract
events <-
  structure(
    list(
      ReservationDate = structure(
        c(4L, 2L, 3L, NA,
          1L), .Label = c(
            "18/12/2006", "1/1/1900", "May 11 2004 12:00AM",
            "May 17 2004 12:00AM"
          ), class = "factor"
      ), OrigEnquiryDate = structure(
        c(1094565600,
          937404000, 1089295200, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""
      ), UnconditionalDate = structure(
        c(1092146400, 935676000,
          1087740000, NA, 1168952400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""
      ),
      ContractsExchangedDate = structure(
        c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1171544400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""
      )
    ), .Names = c(
      "ReservationDate",
      "OrigEnquiryDate", "UnconditionalDate", "ContractsExchangedDate"
    ), row.names = c(54103L, 54090L, 54057L, 135861L, 73433L), class = "data.frame"
  )

ParseDates <- function(x, orders=NULL, threshold=10) {
  # converts to POSIXct if required and replaces 1900-01-01 or similar with na
  if(!is.null(orders)) {
    x <- parse_date_time(x, orders)
  }
  x[abs(difftime(x, as.POSIXct("1900-01-01"), units="days")) < threshold] <- NA
  return(x)
}

# only consider these columns
date.cols <- names(events) %in% c(
  "ReservationDate", "UnconditionalDate", "ContractsExchangedDate", "OrigEnquiryDate"
)

# columns other than these should use the default threshold of 10
date.thresholds <- list("UnconditionalDate"=90, "ContractsExchangedDate"=400)

# columns *other* than these should use the default order of NULL,
#   they skip parsing and go straight to threshold testing
date.orders <- list(
  "SettlementDate"=c("dmY", "bdY I:Mp"),
  "ReservationDate"=c("dmY", "bdY I:Mp")
)

events[date.cols] <- lapply(events[date.cols],
                            ParseDates(events[date.cols],
                                       orders = date.orders,
                                       threshold = date.thresholds))
```

Comment: Your function doesn't run on the first column. `ParseDates(events$Reservation, ...)`. Try it for yourself. Also, you need to pass it as a function so it should be `lapply(events[..],function(x) ParseDates(x,...))`

Comment: Thanks Brandon - I tested against the first column and it works in a new session - probably just a typo but your snippet has 'events$Reservation' instead of 'events$ReservationDate'.  Calling `lapply(events[date.cols], function(x) ParseDates(x,orders = date.orders, threshold = date.thresholds))' seems to execute the same way as the way I tried above.

Comment: RIght now, you're passing the entire data frame as your parameter. You need to use function notation to parameterize your function. From the example of `?lapply`. `x <- list(a = 1:10, beta = exp(-3:3), logic = c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE))`. `lapply(x,mean)` This is essentially equal to `lapply(x, function(x) mean(x))`. You are doing `lapply(x,mean(x))` which is not how lapply works.

Comment: For example, when I run: `ParseDates(events[date.cols][[1]],orders = date.orders, threshold = date.thresholds)` I get ` Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Unknown formats supplied: c `